# Упрощение UNION с JOIN в каждом подзапросе

Tags: mysql, запрос

Есть таблицы:

```
пользователи: users (id, name)
посещения: visits (id, user_id, time)
платежи: pays (id, user_id, time)
```

Необходимо выбрать данные следующего вида:

```
месяц - кол-во посещений - кол-во оплат
```

Составил запрос следующего вида:

```
SELECT time, SUM(visits), SUM(pays) 
FROM (
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(v.`time`, '%Y-%m') AS time, COUNT(l.`id`) AS visits, 0 AS pays
    FROM `visits` v
    WHERE v.`user_id` = '$id' AND v.`time` BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2'
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(v.`time` , '%Y-%m') 

    UNION 

    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(p.`time`, '%Y-%m') AS time, 0 AS visits, COUNT(p.`id`) AS pays
    FROM `pays` p
    WHERE p.`user_id` = '$id' AND p.`time` BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2'
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(p.`time`, '%Y-%m')
) t
GROUP BY time
```

Получаются два практически одинаковых подзапроса, которые уже хочется как-то оптимизировать, но все работает довольно быстро. Но теперь появилась необходимость в этом же запросе вместо `user_id = '$id'` написать выборку из таблицы `users`, например, по полю `name`. Получается, что к каждому из подзапросов добавится конструкция наподобие данной:

```
INNER JOIN `users` u ON u.`name` = '$name` AND l.`user_id` = u.`id`
```

Что автоматически усложняет запрос в разы.

Можно ли этого как-то избежать? Или проще будет уже выполнить два раздельных запроса к БД?

Comment: а что за таблица `logs` еще, которую вы не упомянули?

Comment: _Что автоматически усложняет запрос в разы_ При наличии индексов, необходимых для эффективного выполнения отдельных подзапросов, никакого особенного усложнения нет.

Comment: @Denis ИМХО logs == visits.

Comment: @Denis да, ошибся, Akina прав, поправлю

Comment: @Akina согласен, индексы проставлены, тут скорее больше встает вопрос усложнения общего вида запроса с точки зрения удобства и последующих модификаций

Comment: @segan с точки зрения удобства и прочих наворотов делайте параметрические запросы - не из консоли же Вы их будете выполнять... А ещё лучше не делайте запросы универсальные, они обычно менее эффективны.

Answer (score 2):

Вот такое нужно? Просто добавить name в конечный результат?

```
SELECT t.time,u.name, SUM(t.visits), SUM(t.pays) 
FROM (
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(v.`time`, '%Y-%m') AS time, COUNT(l.`id`) AS visits, 0 AS pays,v.`user_id` AS user_id
    FROM `visits` v
    WHERE v.`user_id` = '$id' AND v.`time` BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2'
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(v.`time` , '%Y-%m') ,v.`user_id`

    UNION 

    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(p.`time`, '%Y-%m') AS time, 0 AS visits, COUNT(p.`id`) AS pays,p.`user_id`
    FROM `pays` p
    WHERE p.`user_id` = '$id' AND p.`time` BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2'
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(p.`time`, '%Y-%m'),p.`user_id`
) t
INNER JOIN `users` u ON u.`name` = '$name` AND t.user_id = u.`id`
GROUP BY t.time,u.`name`
```

Comment: Не совсем то, мне нужно сначала сделать выборку нужных пользователей, а потом по ним уже запустить запросы

Comment: @segan Вам нужен результат. Не старайтесь рассказать серверу, как выполнять запрос, он лучше знает и умеет.

Comment: Насколько я понял идею, в данном запросе идет выборка логов абсолютно всех людей, и только затем из результата с помощью JOIN отсеивается вся основная масса. Запрос работает, согласен, но его производительность оставляет желать лучшего